# Getting Next/Previous Post ID using Current Post ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, fancybox

I want to write a custom next/prev function to dynamically display post information in a fancybox pop-up. So I need to use PHP to get the next and previous Post ID based on whatever Post is currently showing. I know what the current post ID is and I can send that to a function ok, but I can't figure out how to use that ID to obtain the adjacent IDs.

Edit:Here is my code so far (which is not working)

```
<?php
require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");

if (isset($_POST['data'])){
    $post_id = $_POST['data'];
}else{
    $post_id = "";
}
$wp_query->is_single = true;
$this_post = get_post($post_id);
$in_same_cat = false;
$excluded_categories = '';
$previous = false;
$next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);


$post_id = $next_post->id;
$title = $next_post->post_title;

$dataset = array ( "postid"=>$post_id, "posttitle"=>$title );

//Because we want to use json, we have to place things in an array and encode it for json.
//This will give us a nice javascript object on the front side.

echo json_encode($dataset);


?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`get_adjacent_post()` uses the global `$post` as its reference point, so you'll want to replace this:

```
$this_post = get_post($post_id);
```

with this:

```
global $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);
```

WordPress also provides `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post()`, which you can use here instead of using `get_adjacent_post()` with all of those arguments.  Here's the final product:

```
<?php
require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");

if (isset($_POST['data'])){
    $post_id = $_POST['data'];
}else{
    $post_id = "";
}
$wp_query->is_single = true;

global $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);

$previous_post = get_previous_post();
$next_post = get_next_post();

$post_id = $next_post->id;
$title = $next_post->post_title;

$dataset = array ( "postid"=>$post_id, "posttitle"=>$title );

//Because we want to use json, we have to place things in an array and encode it for json.
//This will give us a nice javascript object on the front side.

echo json_encode($dataset);

?>
```

I'm not sure what keys you'd like to use for the IDs and titles of the previous and next posts in the `$dataset` array, so I'll leave that as is for now.

Answer (score 3):

To get this to work I had to change `$next_post->id;` to `$next_post->ID;`, i.e. capitalise `ID`.

I used it in Wordpress on index.php like this – I inserted this at the top of the loop:

```
<div class="work-post" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

then within the loop I use this:
`

```
        if (isset($_POST['data'])){
            $post_id = $_POST['data'];
        }else{
            $post_id = "";
        }
        $wp_query->is_single = true;

        global $post;
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        $next_post = get_next_post();
        $previous_post = get_previous_post();

        ?>

        <!-- call only if a value exists -->
            <?php if($next_post) : ?>
                <a href="#<?php echo $next_post->ID;?>" class="anchorLink"><div>PREV.</div></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- call only if a value exists -->

        <!-- call only if a value exists -->
            <?php if($previous_post) : ?>
                <a href="#<?php echo $previous_post->ID;?>" class="anchorLink"><div>NEXT</div></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- call only if a value exists -->`
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my code, it worked good. $post_id is current post ID.

```
function get_previous_post_id( $post_id ) {
    // Get a global post reference since get_adjacent_post() references it
    global $post;
    // Store the existing post object for later so we don't lose it
    $oldGlobal = $post;
    // Get the post object for the specified post and place it in the global variable
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    // Get the post object for the previous post
    $previous_post = get_previous_post();
    // Reset our global object
    $post = $oldGlobal;
    if ( '' == $previous_post ) 
        return 0;
    return $previous_post->ID; 
} 

function get_next_post_id( $post_id ) {
    // Get a global post reference since get_adjacent_post() references it
    global $post;
    // Store the existing post object for later so we don't lose it
    $oldGlobal = $post;
    // Get the post object for the specified post and place it in the global variable
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    // Get the post object for the next post
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    // Reset our global object
    $post = $oldGlobal;
    if ( '' == $next_post ) 
        return 0;
    return $next_post->ID; 
}
```

Then you just call function. Example:

```
echo get_previous_post_id( $current_id );
echo get_next_post_id( $current_id );
```

Good luck!